# Using the Flexviewer 2.4 I want to toggle layers from one service on/off

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, flex, arcgis-flex-viewer

I have 2 layers in one service. If the user clicks one on, I want the other one to turn off, and vice versa.

I am using the default flexviewer LayerListWidget.mxml and assume this is the place where I would want to put the code to handle the toggle on/off event.

I have seen these posts, but I am not sure it's the right code. Can someone provide me with the right code to use? Thanks in advance.

[esri forum 1](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/32104-URL-Parameters-and-Layer-Visibility?highlight=visibility%20parameter)

[esri forum2](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/23066-Layer-On-Off?highlight=Layer%20visibility)

Answer (score 2):

pdog,

Here is a thread where I answered that in the ESRI Flex Viewer forum:

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/48126-Layer-List-Widget-is-it-possible-to-only-allow-one-selected-layer-at-a-time

Comment: Good work rscheitlin. Keep it up.